# Errors when Sending a Message to a Queue on SQS AWS

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

Getting Errors

- MissingRequiredParameter: Missing required key
- UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key

when trying to Sending a Message to a Queue on SQS AWS, and data returns Null.
what am I doing wrong? message contains correct data.

```
/**
 *
 * @param message
 */
function sendMessage (message) { 
  // Send the message to this other Queue
  sqs.sendMessage(message, function (err, data) {
      if (err) {
        console.log('Error', err)
      } else {
        console.log('Success', data.MessageId)
      }
    }
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what is the `message` in your code!
However, here the `message` should be params of the `sendMessage` function and not the message data itself. Then, it should be like (minimal options):

```
message = {
      MessageBody: JSON.stringify(real_message_content),
      QueueUrl: process.env.SQS_MAILER, <= your queue
};
```